# Python requests SSL error with combined .pem file

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

I have an internal server/api that is signed by an internal sub ca which was signed by the root ca. In my browsers the site is trusted and verified because the root ca and sub ca certs were imported. I can also verify the signing chain for the web server.

I am using python requests library to make calls to the api. I created a .pem file which includes the root ca and sub ca certs

eg

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
snathopONSETUHO...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
snathopONSETUHO...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

When making the requests call I used

`r = requests.get('https://server/api', auth=(user,password), cert='/path/to/cert_bundle.pem')`

The error I recieve is

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SSLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-04e0aff97162> in <module>()
----> 1 r = requests.get('https://host/api/', auth=(user,password), cert='/path/to/cert_bundle.pem')

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.pyc in get(url, **kwargs)
     66
     67     kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', True)
---> 68     return request('get', url, **kwargs)
     69
     70

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.pyc in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     48
     49     session = sessions.Session()
---> 50     response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
     51     # By explicitly closing the session, we avoid leaving sockets open which
     52     # can trigger a ResourceWarning in some cases, and look like a memory leak

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.pyc in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    462         }
    463         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 464         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    465
    466         return resp

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.pyc in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    574
    575         # Send the request
--> 576         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    577
    578         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.pyc in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    429         except (_SSLError, _HTTPError) as e:
    430             if isinstance(e, _SSLError):
--> 431                 raise SSLError(e, request=request)
    432             elif isinstance(e, ReadTimeoutError):
    433                 raise ReadTimeout(e, request=request)

SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:2757)
```

Any ideas why my cert won't validate? I tried reversing the order in the .pem file in case order matters but still cannot get my request to work.

I also tried with `verify=False` which works but not what I want and throws the error

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:769: 
InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding 
certificate verification is strongly advised. See: 
https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html
  InsecureRequestWarning)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're using the wrong parameter to pass the path to the certificate bundle, your code should read:

```
r = requests.get('https://server/api', auth=(user,password), verify='/path/to/cert_bundle.pem')
```

The parameter used for verifying a remote certificate signed by a CA is `verify`. If you only specify `verify=True` then it will use a default internal root certificate store, but you can also pass in a path to your own store as in my code example.

The `cert` parameter is for confirming your own identity to the remote server, which your server probably doesn't care about here.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on the options. I had actually tried verify='cert.pem' but receive `SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:765)` At that point I guess there's something wrong with my cert but I'm not sure what it would be.

Comment: I figured out that my cert_bundle.pem file was not correct. It did not have the full cert chain (root ca and sub ca) certs in the file. After fixing that and using verify instead of cert I was able to get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter in session was wrong
it is not **cert** it is **verify**....

```
import gitlab
import requests

session = requests.Session()
session.verify = 'ca_cert.pem'
domain = 'https://your.gitlab.server.com'
gl = gitlab.Gitlab(domain, private_token='your access token', api_version="4", session=session)
gl.auth()

pathToProject = "path/to/repo"
project = gl.projects.get(pathToProject)
items = project.repository_tree()

print(items)
```