# Python requests Library SSL error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

first ever question: 
I'm getting the following result:

> File "D:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 70, in get
>   return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
>
> File "D:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 56, in
>   request return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
>
> File "D:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 475,
>   in request resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
>
> File "D:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 596,
>   in send r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
>
> File "D:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 497,
>   in send raise SSLError(e, request=request)
>
> requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

This traces back to one line of code here:

```
import requests, os, bs4, calendar #, sys
import urllib.request

while not year>2016:
    print('Downloading page {}...'.format(url))

    res = requests.get(loginpageURL, verify='false', auth=('username', 'password')) #this is the line that doesn't work
    res = requests.get(url, verify='false') #but I have tried it without that line and this line also doesn't work
    res.raise_for_status()

    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text)
    print(soup)
```

I have researched the issue extensively, and come to the conclusion that it is actually an issue with the requests/urllib3 libraries themselves.

At first, I tried the verify='false' fix [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667960/python-requests-throwing-up-sslerror). It didn't work. Someone [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30830901/python-requests-throwing-ssl-errors) said to install new openSSL and certifi, they appear to be installed and up to date on my system. 
Found the bug has a great writeup on [here](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/3058). No solution from what I could see.
It has been identified on github as a known issue [here](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/2863).

When, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33137337/python-requests-ssl-error-with-combined-pem-file) answer, I tried to change verify='false' to verify='cacert.pem' (which I included in the project directory), it threw this error:
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645)

Now I'm sitting here just wanting to get this one code snippet to run - I'm trying to bulk download a few hundred zip files from a website - in spite of the known issue with the library. I'm relatively new to python, but especially new to web scraping, so this is a steep learning curve for me. Any help would be appreciated. Do I need to go so far as [scrapping requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34310878/python-authentication-not-recognised-urllib2-requests-asp-net)?

Thanks!

Comment: Actually not sure, but I think I faced this issue a while ago and found out some SSL modules were missing. Nice question btw.

Comment: You may well be right, and that is where my knowledge breaks down. I've already tried using the library MechanicalSoup and it throws a similar error when I try to use a get: 
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ```
> res = requests.get(loginpageURL, verify='false', ...
> ```

Verify takes either a boolean (i.e. True or False) or a path which is then used as path for the trust store. Your specification `'false'` is a string and not a boolean and it will therefore try to use the file `false` as CA store. This file cannot be found and thus results in `No such file or directory`.

To fix this you have to use `verify=False`, i.e. use the boolean value.

Apart from that disabling the validation is a bad idea and should only be done for testing or when the security offered by TLS is completely irrelevant for the program. For a login page like in your case disabling validation is probably a bad thing because a man in the middle can thus easily sniff the username and password.

Comment: Thanks Steffen, as you can see above, I changed that approach to indicate the path to cacert.pem and it threw a `requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645)` error.

Comment: @DK.: this is a different question then. But in short: either the root CA for this site is not in cacert.pem or the server fails to deliver a chain certificate. Which is these is the case can probably only be said if both the URL and the contents of your cacert.pem are known.